# Get value from database in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, database

I have this table in my Magento database:
'manthan_marketplace_vendorproduct':

```
    entity_id  product_id  user_id
       3          35          2 
       4          36          2
```

It shows all the products that have been added by each user(seller)
I can access the user_id value in my phtml file in this directory:

```
app\design\frontend\base\default\template\marketplace\seller\profile.phtml
```

by this code:

```
$seller = $this->sellerProfile();
$seller['user_id'];
```

but **$seller** which is an array of objects, doesn't have any product_id. So I should use that table to get all product_id into an array
but the Magento framework is unknown for me.

Help me please, thanks!

Comment: You need to get collection for your table using model. And then add filter on the collection to get Products of a seller.

Comment: thanks with your guidance i found that  I have model with 'vendorproduct.php' name and with this code  I can access to values:                                   
  $seller = Mage::getModel('marketplace/vendorproduct')->getCollection();     $seller->getData();

Comment: did you get solution for your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code to get product IDs for a seller.

```
$sellerData = Mage::getModel('marketplace/vendorproduct')->getCollection()‌​
->addFieldToFilter('user_id',$seller['user_id']) // Filter using seller Id
->getColumnValues('product_id'); // Get Only Product IDs
print_r($sellerData);
```